# Testing loss of internet connection during javascript execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, acceptance-testing

## My problem

I am looking to test how a script handles a loss of internet connection part way through execution. At a lower level I simply need to cause a number of network request to fail after certain point in the script.

I am attempting to keep this test as end to end as possible without mocking any javascript units.

## My thoughts on how I might achieve this

Chrome has a useful toggle in it's dev tools under the network tab which simulates a loss of internet connection. I would like to toggle this from the script I am executing (in a similar manner to how `debugger` triggers a breakpoint under the sources tab).

I suspect this won't be easy as it would create a significant security hole if web pages could trigger this. However, if there is anyway to hack Chrome into a state where it is possible, possibly using an extension or Chromium I'm all ears.

**Is there a way to toggle the Chrome 'offline' dev tool from javascript?**

**Failing this is there any other way to simulate a loss of connection / cause network requests to fail from javascript? (By the way I'm not married to Chrome)**

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom chrome extension with the `debugger` permission and then [attach](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-attach) to the tab. Then you would call Network.enable on that tab and then start [emulating network conditions](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-2/Network/#method-emulateNetworkConditions) (e.g. go offline)

You could communicate with your custom extension (e.g. telling it to go offline at a specific time) using [onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessageExternal).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also try this?

```js
setInterval("stop()", 100);
```

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop), `window.stop()` stops the currently-loading resources from loading, like pressing the "stop" button. Repeatedly doing that on a loop would simulate a network loss.

If you wanted to programmatically disconnect and also **restore** the connection, maybe something like

```js
var interval = setInterval("stop()", 100);
// To restore connectivity
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to set a breakpoint in the `Sources` tab at the critical point & then manually go offline in the `Network` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Javascript try leveraging asynchronous calls or promises to simulate this scenario.